# Sencha Ext JS 4 framework examples on IIS 7 configured NOT on port 80 doesn't work

Tags: php, iis-7, extjs4, extjs, port80

I figured this might be a Sencha Ext JS 4 framework issue, not a server issue, so I'll just give you the link to this question.

https://serverfault.com/questions/293476/sencha-ext-js-4-framework-examples-on-iis-7-configured-not-on-port-80-doesnt-wor

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't seems to be a ExtJS4 framework issue at all, unless magically you can access your localhost but not ExtJS framework. Your question posted at severvault seems to be as simple as port forwarding issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the link for the answer on Server Fault.  It was the server's fault this time.

Comment: Yep. ExtJS is targeting client side application and has rare or nothing to do with server scripting.